# Problema Sign in Google al instalar apk

Tags: android-studio, autenticación, google-signin

Buenas tengo una aplicación desarrollada en android studio, cuando hago la instalación en un dispositivo en emulador se puede logear con (email y contraseña) y con (sign-in de google) sin problema, cuando hago la instalación desde el computador a un dispositivo fisico igual corren bien; pero el problema esta que cuando genero el apk y al logear con (email y contraseña) FUNCIONA, pero con (sign-in de google) NO FUNCIONA, como le comente, esto sucede cuando instalo con el APK generado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]